# Why is the index of a point lying outside a closed curve always zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand what Ahlfors is trying to say in this point.  He says

> If $\gamma$ lies inside of a circle, then $n(\gamma,a)=0$ for all points $a$ outside of the same circle

His explanation is that

> As a point set $\gamma$ is closed and bounded.  Its complement is open and can be represented as a union of disjoint regions, the components of the complement.  We shall say, for short, that $\gamma$ **determines** these regions.  If the complementary regions are considered in the extended plane, there is exactly one which contains the point at infinity.  Consequently, $\gamma$ determines one and only one unbounded region.

However I don't quite see how this ties into his point.  He says this has something to do with Cauchy's theorem on a disc.  However, I'm pretty sure it only holds on the "interior" of $\gamma$.   Since the region containing the point at infinity is not an open disc, I'm not sure how Cauchy's theorem on a disc applies.  The only conclusion I seem to be able to justify is that the theorem is not applicable to the region outside the curve.  How does he come to the conclusion that it is zero?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the reference is to page 116 of Lars V. Ahlfors, *Complex Analysis* (3rd ed. McGraw-Hill 1979).

What's missing is simply the last line of the previous page!

Starting from the bottom of page 115, the full quotation is:

> The following property is an immediate consequence of Theorem 4 [Cauchy's Theorem in a Disk]:
>
> (i) *If $\gamma$ lies inside of a circle, then $n(\gamma,a)=0$ for all points $a$ outside of the same circle.*
>
> As a point set $\gamma$ is closed and bounded. [$\ldots$ continues as in the OP $\ldots$]

The passage immediately following (i) is not the proof of (i).

The intended proof of (i) is exactly the one given in @martin-r's answer.

(That answer is likely to be expanded later, so I'm posting this as CW - it's too long to be a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma$ lies inside of a circle $C$ and $a$ is outside of $C$ then the function $z \mapsto 1/(z-a)$ is holomorphic in the interior of $C$, and therefore
$$
 n(\gamma,a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i }\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-a} dz = 0
$$
by Cauchy's integral theorem.

Also $a \mapsto n(\gamma,a)$ is constant on each component of the complement of $\gamma$. Together with the above result it follows that $n(\gamma,a) = 0$ for all $a$ in the unbounded component of the complement of $\gamma$.

Comment: How does the complement of $\gamma$ being a disjoint union factor into this?  What I got out of his reasoning that something about including the point at infinity meant that the exterior open set had some special property which meant that the integral would be zero.  It seems that the method using a holomorphism just swaps the two open sets?